# Best practice to compress generated PDF using iText7

Tags: pdf, compression, itext7

I have existing / source PDF source document and I copy selected pages from it and generate destination PDF with selected pages. Every page in existing / source document is scanned in different resolution and it varies in size:

1. generated document with 4 pages => 175 kb
2. generated document with 4 pages => 923 kb (I suppose this is because of higher scan resolution of each page in source document)

What would be best practice to compress this pages? 
Is there any code sample with compressing / reducing size of final PDF which consists of copied pages of source document in different resolution?

Kindest regards

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I need code example for compression using iText ... I tried to write question politely :))

Comment: And it's great that you followed our Be Nice policy here! Unfortunately though, this community does not like when people ask for code examples because it fallsunder the off-topic guidelines that I mentioned above. We prefer if you show us some of the code you tried to implement, and then explain what doesn't work about it/what you need help with. That is much more likely to get you some decent responses and maybe even get rid of some of the downvotes you received

Comment: As a partial explanation to the increase in file size: well ,what did you expect when you replaced text with images :)? That is, if by scanning you meant the actual physical act of scanning in a printed out version of the pdf. If you're copying from one page to another, have a look at the smartmode writer-property

Comment: It may sound a bit mean, but you get a vastly better response rate if you add code that is obviously wrong but *almost* there, than when you add no code at all. That's because of how the brain of developers work. We don't read the text of your question, we read your code. We get enough text-only mail from managers, seeing your code makes you our equal and we're much likely to help you. One of the hidden secrets of Stack Overflow. Psychology 101. ;-)

Comment: @Lexi: Thank you Lexi for advice, I'll put code sample when I ask something next time.

Comment: @Samuel: I didn't replace text with images, I got source document as set of scanned images from external app.

Comment: @Amedee: I agree with you :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just adding scans to a pdf document, it makes sense for the size of the resulting document to go up if you're using a high resolution image.

Keep in mind that iText is a pdf library. Not an image-manipulation library.

You could of course use regular old java to attempt to compress the images.

```
public static void writeJPG(BufferedImage bufferedImage, OutputStream outputStream, float quality) throws IOException
{
    Iterator<ImageWriter> iterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter imageWriter = iterator.next();
    ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(quality);
    ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(outputStream);
    imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);
    IIOImage iioimage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
    imageWriter.write(null, iioimage, imageWriteParam);
    imageOutputStream.flush();
}
```

But really, putting scanned images into a pdf makes life so much more difficult. Imagine the people who have to handle that document after you. They open it, see text, try to select it, and nothing happens.

Additionaly, you might change the `WriterProperties` when creating your `PdfWriter` instance:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest,
    new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true));
```

Full compression mode will compress certain objects into an object stream, and it will also compress the cross-reference table of the PDF. Since most of the objects in your document will be images (which are already compressed), compressing objects won't have much effect, but if you have a large number of pages, compressing the cross-reference table may result in smaller PDF files.

Comment: Bruno, thank you for explanation how full-compression works.  My source PDF didn't have a lot of pages / max. 10 pages and it contains scanned physical document through another application and I cannot change the way how source PDF is generated. Bruno was right for full-compression, when I used them I got very small reduction size. Also, I considered to put regular Java compression you suggested, but at the end we stored generated documents on file system and we didn't need to compress images. Thank you one more time for answers.

Comment: You are confusing Bruno and Joris. :)

Comment: @Amedee: I hope not confusing too much :))